# FizzBuzz in Ruby with without 3 && 5

Tags: ruby, conditional-statements, fizzbuzz

Ok so I'm trying to hash this out for practice. So my thought is that we could prevent an extra check from the `num % 3 == 0 && num % 5 == 0`

1
2
-Fizz
+3
4
Buzz
-Fizz
+6
7
8
-Fizz
+9
Buzz
11
-Fizz
+12
13
14
FizzBuzz

With this attempt we are missing "Fizz" but get "Buzz" and "FizzBuzz". Any thought or ideas for a Ruby solution?

```
def fizzbuzz(num)
  # if num % 3 == 0 && num % 5 == 0
  #   "FizzBuzz"
  # Push the String "Fizz"/"Buzz"
  result = ""
  if num % 3 == 0
    result << "Fizz"
  end
  if num % 5 == 0
    result << "Buzz"
  else
    num
  end
end

# Ruby creates these sequences using the ''..'' and ''...'' range operators. 
# The two-dot form creates an inclusive range, 
# while the three-dot form creates a range that excludes the specified high value.

def fizzbuzz_printer
  (1..100).each do |num|
    puts fizzbuzz(num)
  end
end

fizzbuzz_printer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A method in Ruby returns the value of its last expression unless you explicitly `return`.

Your last expression is:

```
  if num % 5 == 0
    result << "Buzz"
  else
    num
  end
```

In this case, if the number is not divisible by `5`, you just return `num`.

You likely want:

```
def fizzbuzz(num)
  # if num % 3 == 0 && num % 5 == 0
  #   "FizzBuzz"
  # Push the String "Fizz"/"Buzz"
  result = ""
  if num % 3 == 0
    result << "Fizz"
  end
  if num % 5 == 0
    result << "Buzz"
  elsif !result.empty?
    result
  else
    num
  end
end
```

Comment: Is it common practice to try and always stick to the implicit last return? Or are there instances when being explicit with your return is better?

Comment: That's verging into opinion territory, certainly, but I've found it best to only use an explicit return if I need to actually return _early_.

Answer (score 2):

Without `num % 3 == 0 && num % 5 == 0` LOL:

```
def fizzbuzz(num)
  if num % 15 == 0
    "FizzBuzz"
  elsif num % 3 == 0
    "Fizz"
  elsif num % 5 == 0
    "Buzz"
  else
    num
  end
end
```

Using `presence` from ActiveSupport:

```
def fizzbuzz(num)
  result = ""

  result << "Fizz" if num % 3 == 0
  result << "Buzz" if num % 5 == 0

  result.presence || num
end
```

(will work in rails, or in plain ruby with `require 'active_support/core_ext/object/blank'`)

Comment: Or just `result.empty? ? num : result`

Comment: @Chris it's not interesting, because the answer will be the same as yours :)

Comment: i love this! xD

Answer (score 1):

A little archaic, but this would work:

```
def fizzbuzz(num)
  (result ||= '') << "Fizz" if num % 3 == 0
  (result ||= '') << "Buzz" if num % 5 == 0
  result || num
end
```

The expression `result ||= ''` is a conditional assignment: if `result` has a truthy value, it just returns it, but if it is falsey (here: `nil`), it first assigns an empty string to it and then returns `result`.

On the first line the conditional assignment actually isn't needed because `result` can't have any value beside `nil`. You could just as well write `result = 'Fizz' if num % 3 == 0` but I preferred to have that symmetry.

If you're working with frozen string literals, you can use `+''` instead of `''`.